# iOS - Today Extension Slow Network (URLSession)

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlsession, today-extension, urlsession

I have a today extension (iOS 10, Swift 3) that contains a `URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: baseURL)` call and for some reason this request can take a long time to load. Sometimes the request is loaded in under a second, sometimes it takes up to 15 seconds.

I am managing the server the URL session is requesting data from and the server is reporting that the page is being served up in under a second, however the today extension sometimes takes up to 15 seconds to load the data (by load the data I mean specifically load the data from this call).

The strange thins is the actual app loads data from the exact same URL and it always loads in under a second within the full app.

Are there certain configurations that I need to make to have the today extension load data faster? Are you supposed to load data in a different way in today extensions?

Here is the code block where I am making the request:

```
self.startTime = Date().timeIntervalSince1970

let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: baseURL) { (data, response, error) in
        print("Time Taken: \(Date().timeIntervalSince1970 - self.startTime)")

        // process the data
}

task.resume()
```

Comment: make sure you update the UI in the main queue

Comment: I'm using grand central dispatch correctly to update the UI, thats not the issue here, for some reason the dataTask takes a long time

Comment: Should I not be using the shared singleton? Should I be creating a new URLSession() object instead?